# Gatsby Link Not Respecting activeClassName

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have the following:

```
    <Link className="nav-link" activeClassName="active-link"
     activeStyle={{ color: "red" }} to="/">welcome</Link>
```

The style is applied properly, but the classname `("active-link")` is not.  Checking the dom, the classname is not there on the element.

Where should I look for the problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you're passing an `href` prop to `Link`? I suspect that you're actually on `/#` and not `/`, causing neither `active*` prop to be applied, but you haven't shared enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @coreyward Its strange, because it respects the activeStyle prop. I did strip out the href, same result. I'm just about to hand code a solution.